# Routing mistake on a bridged over wifi LAN

Tags: wireless-networking, routing, subnet, bridge-router

I have a problem with routing on my LAN. I understand why it didn't work but I can't see an elegant solution.

In a multi-building site a MikroTik router is taking care of the WAN connection for everybody and connecting different subnetworks with different needs.

One of these subnetworks is spread out over multiple buildings through a WiFi AP connected to the MikroTik router and several client stations, one at each building. All of those WiFi devices work in bridged mode so every user is directly connecting to the MikroTik router.

If we see the network as a flower the base is the MikroTik router, the WiFi AP on the roof the center of the flower, and the petals are the WiFi clients with all the clients behind them.

My problem is that all the clients have no problem connecting to other subnetworks or to the Internet. But they are not able to connect to another client of the same subnetwork but on different "petals".

Should I use different subnetwork for each petal?

- Router 192.168.2.1/24
- AP on roof in bridge mode 192.168.2.101/24
- client on two buildings in bridge mode 192.168.2.102/24 and 192.168.2.122/24
- laptop 192.168.2.116/24 is connected through *.102 while Raspberry 192.168.2.123 is connected through *.122

The laptop could only reach the AP on the roof 2.101 or the router 2.1 and never the other client, for example 2.122 or 2.123

Comment: "do not find the way to connect to client of the same subnetwork but on different "petals"". please can you edit and explain that "without a flower" with IPs and subnets,

Comment: On mikrotik the relevant interface 192.168.2.1/24 with dhcp enabled for that subnetwork. From that interface we move to the AP in bridge mode on the roof (address *.2.101) then to a couple of wifi client both in bridge mode, say *.2.102  and *.2.122. My laptop (address 192.168.2.116/24) is connected trough the wifi router (configured as client in bridge mode) with ip *.102, while the device I would reach is connected trough the wifi router (configured as client in bridge mode) with ip*.2.122 and it's ip address is 192.168.2.123/24

Comment: What about subnet mask?

Comment: Same for everybody 255.255.255.0 (/24)

Comment: ok make your DNS on your laptop static, the first DNS X.X the second DNS 2.X, and tell me what the result, you can reach that client "PC" now or not?

Comment: I'm on linux and resolv.conf contains:
># Generated by NetworkManager
>nameserver 192.168.2.1
so that should be right

Comment: I know your microtik make everything, I am troubleshooting your issues, you said your laptop IP 2.X and the bridge X.102 ?! there is two DHCP service here! your mikrotic 2.X the other one from where? to reach different subnet you must have a router between them!

Comment: You can use routing or bridging. Either one will work. For routing, they will need to be in different subnetworks. For bridging, you will have to use some bridge-over-WiFi technology, like WDS.

Comment: No, only one dhcp, every device I talked about is on the same subnetwork and are configured by the same dhcp server. Mikrotik 192.168.2.1 - AP 192.168.2.101 - wifi clients (192.168.2.102 and 192.168.2.122) then the final devices one is 2.116 and the other 2.123

Comment: The wifi device are all in bridge mode to be "transparent" to the final devices but then the routing isn't working properly between devices connected trough different wifi client bridge.

Comment: Probably I should use different subnet so that routing could be done properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You need to disable Wireless Isolation** (sometimes called *Client Isolation*) on the wireless AP that's connected to your router. Wireless Isolation prevents wireless clients from communicating with other wireless clients connected to the same base station (AP).

In your case, the AP connected to your router is the "base station" and the APs located at each building are its wireless clients.  Wireless Isolation is preventing the building's APs from communicating with another, which in turn prevents the nodes in a particular building from communicating with nodes in another building.

Simply disable Wireless Isolation/Client Isolation on the AP connected to the router and intra-building connectivity should begin working.

Comment: Thank's. That was the perfect answer for my specific situation.